# BLE - Bluetooth connection issue iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app, I am trying to connect to BLE device from inside the app. At times, I get a warning saying "Device cannot be connected, please try to reboot it". When I turn off and turn on Bluetooth, it works fine. Is this an issue with the BLE Device I am using? Or is this an issue with my code.

Regards,
Vamshi

Comment: Where is ur code ?you should put it in the question description.